# Can I have multiple kafka consumer instance on one JVM?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a situation where I want to use multiple consumer on on JVM. I am using Spring-Cloud-Stream.

Functioning will be like:- I will deploy my application on JVM 1, and If I set instance=3, then 3 consumers should be create.

Is there any configuration available for **Spring-cloud-stream**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `concurrency` in [Consumer Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_consumer_properties).